# replacing every letter with its position in the alphabet with map function is sorted by alphabet order and not by typed order

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

i just created a function to replace every letter with its position in the alphabet, but it is sorted in order of the alphabet. for example, if i type 'Alex' the positions should be (1, 12, 5, 24), but instead is returning (1, 5, 12, 24). what am i doing wrong?

this is my code:

```
let result = [];
let alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" ];

function replace(word) {
  let wordformat = word.split('');

  alphabet.map((letter, i) => {
    wordformat.map((word, l) => {
      if (word === letter) {
        result.push((i = 1 + i));
      }
    });
  });

  console.log(result);
}

replace('alex');
```

EDIT: I made a mistake on what i expected from the output. It is already fixed.

Comment: how did 12 come first

Comment: *"for example, if i type 'Alex' the positions should be (12, 1, 5, 24)"* What rule determines that? "A" is the first element in your array, so with your `1 +` that would be position 1...?

Comment: It's not the problem, but [don't use `map` when you're not using the array it creates](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/). Also, there's no point in assigning to `i` in `result.push(i = 1 + i);`, you're about to throw away the `i` parameter when the callback returns. Just `result.push(i + 1);`.

Comment: you're iterating over it in the wrong order. do `wordformat.map` and then `alphabet.map` inside of that -- but also don't use `.map` at all, like TJ says. Use `.foreach` or another way of iterating

Comment: In order to get answers, you are going to need to describe why it should be **12, 1, 5, 24** and not **1, 12, 5, 24**.

Comment: For simple lattin chars like this you could also use `charCodeAt` instead of that array. eg.   `'x'.charCodeAt(0) - 96`  would give you the 24. etc.

Comment: Sorry, i saw my mistake. I already fixed. It is as you said.  I want to return 1, 12, 5, 24 @imvain2

Comment: also instead of an array you can use an object like {a:1,b:2..} for constant lookup. this ofcourse if u don't want to use charCodeAt

Comment: Why do you use map, but do not actually use map as intended?

Comment: `Array.from(word).map(c => alphabet.indexOf(c))`

Comment: @epascarello - You can always replace `Array.from(x).map(mapFn)` with `Array.from(x, mapFn)` (I always used to forget, too, had to be reminded about a dozen times). `Array.from`: `Array.from(word, c => alphabet.indexOf(c.toLowerCase()) + 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with `map()` that returns the result array.

Also I use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the index of the letter in the array.

```js
let alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" ];

function replace(word) {
  return word.split('')
    .map((letter)=> alphabet.indexOf(letter) + 1);
}

console.log(replace('alex')); // [  1,  12,  5,  24 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the spread syntax to convert the uppercase version of the string into an array, and then map each uppercase letter to an ASCII character code. Then, subtract 64 to get to regular alphabetic order starting with A=1, because A has the ASCII code of 65.

```js
console.log([...'Alex'.toUpperCase()].map(i=>i.charCodeAt(0)-64))
```

Comment: you have a habit of posting code only answers. Link to relevant resources (ie [`charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) documentation) describe what you've done and how it addresses the OP's question. Also this doesn't address why the OP's code isn't giving the expected result

Comment: @pilchard I guess I'm not well-calibrated enough as to when code is self explanatory

Comment: A good answer will always have more than a snippet

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you should have `wordformat` being iterated over first, and then `alphabet` inside of that loop.

```js
let result = [];
let alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" ];

function replace(word) {
  let wordformat = word.split('');

  wordformat.map((letter, l) => {
    alphabet.map((word, i) => {
      if (word === letter) {
        result.push((i = 1 + i));
      }
    });
  });

  console.log(result);
}

replace('alex');
```

Comment: the downvote is probably because you used map without using its return array